# iterating an array to extract a value from firebase database in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

might sound like a basic question--but I'm not seeing where I am going wrong..

I end up with either of these two scenarios:

1. I keep getting the error "Could not cast value of type __NSCFNumber to NSSTring". if I use `extractedSku = skuList[i]!.value["sku"] as! String`
2. If I remove `as! String` it saves it, but it isn't saved as a string. How do I get this to be saved as a string?

---

I have appended data from firebase into an array

```
skuArray = [AnyObject?]()
```

in viewDidLoad, I am iterating skuArray to extract the 'sku' and store into a variable.

```
var skuArray = [AnyObject?]()
var productDetailArray = [AnyObject?]()
```

data stored in Sku Array is:

```
[Optional(Snap (aRandomKey) {
    active = 1;
    sku = 888888;
})]
```

viewDidLoad:

```
let skuList = self.skuArray

for var i = 0; i < skuList.count ; ++i{
    let extractedSku = skuList[i]!.value["sku"] as! String

    // go into database and extract "products" details by sku
    self.databaseRef.child("products/\(extractedSku)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

    self.productDetailArray.append(snapshot)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the underlying type is `NSNumber`, use the `stringValue` property to get a `String`:

```
if let extractedSku = (skuList[i]?.value["sku"] as? NSNumber)?.stringValue {
    // use extractedSku which is of type String
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you @vacawama  for your help and advise.